# Can a Fusion Tables Heatmap be used in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth, google-fusion-tables, heat-map

From the Fusion Tables web interface there's an option to view a heatmap, which draws on top of Google Maps.

From the Fusion Tables map view there's an option to Export To KML, which allows the Fusion Table **points** to be displayed in Google Earth.

Is there a way to add the **heatmap** to Google Earth?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official answer from Google's Fusion Tables team is that this is not currently possible. I've added an enhancement request for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a Network link (KML) for your data to be displayed in Google Earth.

This Official Tutorial

"Create a dynamic link to your map for Google Earth

You can also create a dynamic link from Google Earth to your Fusion Table, so that any changes to your data online will be reflected in Google Earth.

You can add more rows, edit data within Fusion Tables, or use the Fusion Tables API to change the data programmatically.

**Note: Your map must be not require sign in for the dynamic link to work. Make the map Public or Unlisted.**

To create the dynamic link, start at the map view (Visualize > Map):

```
Click Get KML Network Link
Copy the URL in the box
Go to Google Earth and click on the Add menu > Network Link
Paste the URL into the Link field and click OK
Your map should appear in Google Earth."
```

http://earth.google.com/outreach/tutorial_fusion_publish.html#networkkml

Comment: Looks promising, thanks. This brings the points across but not the heatmap, though. Toggling the heatmap option on/off doesn't change any of the properties of the network link's URL. Any clues? I'll also try the fusion tables user forum.